# User defined function to change variables types to factors

Tags: r, variables, user-defined-functions, categorical-data

This is for a class, so I realize there are easier ways to accomplish the task but I need it to be in the form of a user defined function.

I have created the following code to convert the needed variables to factors.

#### Convert factors

```
columns <- c("sex", "medicationUse", "event", "supplementUse")
raw[columns] <- lapply(raw[columns], factor)
```

However, I cannot come up with a user defined function to accomplish this that returns the updated dataset...
If anyone could give me some tips, it would be greatly appreciated. Ive hit a major road block.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason this doesn't work for you?

```
my_fun <- function(data,columns){
   data[columns] <- lapply(data[columns], factor)
   data
}
```

Comment: It runs without errors, but when I check the variable type using str(data), it has not been converted to a factor.

Comment: @AndreaCalkins Works fine for me. You are aware that functions don't magically alter objects in the global environment; you have to assign the result of the function to see the change?